# Nodemon stuck at restarting due to changes for Next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js, nodemon

My nodemon keeps getting stuck at restarting due to changes. I am currently using Next.js framework. I have tried installing and uninstalling nodemon but it doesn't work.

Following is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "next_js_proj",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@artsy/fresnel": "^1.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.14",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "next": "^10.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.8",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "nodemailer-sendgrid-transport": "^0.2.0",
    "nookies": "^2.3.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "6.0.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
    "react-toastify": "^6.0.5",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.2.0",
    "validator": "^13.0.0"
  }
}
```

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const next = require("next");
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const nextApp = next({ dev });
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler();
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config.env" });
const connectDb = require("./utilsServer/connectDb");
connectDb();
app.use(express.json());
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
    app.use("/api/signup", require("./api/signup"));
    app.use("/api/auth", require("./api/auth"));
    app.all("*", (req, res) => handle(req, res));

    server.listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`Hello, Express server running on ${PORT}`);
    });
});
```

Initially when i start up the server, it works

After I have made subsequent changes, it doesn't work

[image]

Kindly advise, thank you very much

Comment: We're are experiencing the same problem. Have not changed a thing since last week.

Comment: @KiprasT so u are having this same exact problem as well ?

Comment: Do you have a nodemon config file? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: It is okay, I solved it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this nodemon issue in next js.

a. I downloaded nodemon in dev dependency of 2.0.7 . Seems like the newer versions are causing problems in my local.

b. Update the scripts in package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  }
```

c. Create nodemon.json in root directory

```
{
    "verbose": true,
    "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".next"
    ],
    "watch": [
        "server/**/*",
        "server.js",
        "api/",
        "validators/",
        "models/"
    ],
    "ext": "js json"
}
```

Nodemon is currently watching server.js , files inside api folder etc. If you want nodemon to watch any other folders, just add it in inside the watch array. So if you want nodemon to watch files inside a directory call foo, just update it nodemon.js to the following

```
{
    "verbose": true,
    "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".next"
    ],
    "watch": [
        "server/**/*",
        "server.js",
        "api/",
        "validators/",
        "models/",
        "foo/"
    ],
    "ext": "js json"
}
```

d. Run npm dev, it should be working.